# Customize application for different customers

Tags: windows, winforms, c#-4.0

Based on a specific application (bakery ERP), I need to create a new branch as a general purpose ERP with basic functionality (invoices, orders, work orders, customer communications...).

This new branch must be customizable for each client: print formats, application colors and icons/images, and restricted access to some application parts...

I've read about resource files for text/icons/image customization, but I need some help or alternatives, maybe defining an Interface to provide needed resources.

I use DevExpress components, so, print formats, and forms layout can be customized storing formats and layouts in files. However, main form has to be completely redesigned, and i wonder about the best way to do this. ¿this can be done with a little project containing the main form and implementing an interface providing custom images for buttons and other customizations?

Apart from layout customization, I need to restrict access to some parts of ERP for each customer, but behavior customization will be minimal or nonexistent, so, maybe I can personalize behavior with an xml config file for each customer.

Independently of my ideas, I thank you for any idea or comment about mu purpose: interface customization for each client, and minimal behavior customization. Don't need complex solutions like Workflow Foundation or completely pug-in based development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only format of prints and screen images, just use resource files or database configurations.

If you need functionality to be changed - use interfaces and inject their implementation via some framework, like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx), for example.

And your English is good, no need to sorry

Comment: Thanks, i'll review MEF in near future, if functionality need to be changed. How can i exchange resource files for each project? I know there are many information about resorce files usage, but i need an start point because of tons of info i've found.

Comment: Just have one project, where all the appropriate data loads from resource files, and exchange them for each client. Pretty easy to maintain some sets of resources, if it's .resx files or .xml's or images or anything else you want to use

Comment: Ok, so, is as easy as, in example, mantain a folder with resources in xml (layouts) and image files (icons), and loading appropiate resources is responsability of each form. it's ok?

Comment: Yes, something like this. May be all the resources should be loaded in one place and you should give your forms an interface to them. It may help when you'll have f.e. incomplete set, but you'll be able to set default values for missing fields from one place.

Comment: But .Net resource files are compliled whitin the project exe, so, they need to be in a new project for each customization?

Comment: You have two options - or don't add them to project, and read them from some directory, or, if you want to add them to project - right click on file, select properties and choose "copy" instead of "embedded resource"